# Android youtube in webview

Tags: android, webview, youtube, loaddata

I have using `Webview` to display some html data in my app. I am using the following code.

```
WebView featureview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.featureview);
WebSettings webSettings = featureview.getSettings(); 
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
featureview.loadData(featureDescription, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Some of the html data has embedded video from youtube using code like `<iframe height='390' frameborder='0' width='640' allowfullscreen='' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/8xgkw67o0Gc' title='YouTube video player'></iframe>`. But it is giving black screen. what is the problem in code? Here I like to add I have installed the flash player and I am trying in in Android 2.2 device.

Comment: I'd also like to know if you have solved this and how?

Comment: Check out my answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24592012/2371425

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Or the non-deprecated equivalent:

```
webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

Comment: This worked for me. @dev-android should try this and accept the answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: This doesn't work for most cases. Check out my answer over here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/24592012/2371425

Comment: `setPluginState` is now deprecated too.

Answer (score 0):

Enable javascript

```
 myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
 WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings(); 
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
 myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");
```

see this links

http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/play-youtube-videos-with-youtube-app-from-webview-t50422.html

Comment: I don't want to open any youtube url, I just want to open a play which is embedded in html content. However I have added setJavaScriptEnabled , but it is giving same result.