# Android webview cannot render youtube video embedded via iframe

Tags: android, webview, youtube

This is about loading youtube videos using latest embedded format (iframe) inside a webview.

Example of the iframe embed format

```
<iframe width="637" height="358" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/olC42gO-Ln4?fs=1&amp;feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Test the code on Android 2.3.3 & 3.2 devices (HTC Desire & Asus Transformer), the webview would only show a black rectangle.

I tried a similar embed from vimeo

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/35693267" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

In 2.3, video played correctly 
In 3.2, a black rectangle flashed and disappeared, the iframe area is blank.

Finally if the old embed format (using the object tag) is used, the video is displayed properly inside the webview in both 2.3.3 & 3.2.

I have checked related questions and added

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

in the application and/or activity tag but still no video in both 2.3 & 3.2 devices.

This is a big problem because more websites are now using the newest format (iframe) to embed their youtube videos. Android/Youtube Team, please take a look at this problem.

Comment: You should this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592012/2371425 as it actually solves the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android browsers are utterly buggy what comes to video playback and embedding. It simply does not work across devices. Trying to get it working is just waste of your time. My suggestion is that you don't try to include `<iframe>` but simply provide a thumbnail of the video which directly links to YouTube page or h264 file.

Earlier discussion, with a possible solution.

[Google Reader-esque optimizing of WebViews on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586475/google-reader-esque-optimizing-of-webviews-on-android)

Comment: You are right. I further found out that the app would be all mess up if you rotate the device when the video is playing. I ended up using the thumbnail & link solution suggested.

Comment: How do you determine what the link is to a youtube or vimeo h264 file?

Comment: Check out my answer below. My answer solves the problem and is really simple.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. The original question was three years ago, so luckily Android has gone forward since then.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to play  videos within your `WebView` you NEED to load the data with a base URL!

**DONT** do this:

```
mContentWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, webViewContentString,
            "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

**DO THIS INSTEAD**:

```
    //veryVeryVery important for playing the videos!
    mContentWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(theBaseUrl, webViewConentString,
            "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

The Base URL will be the something like the "original" url of what you are displaying in your `WebView`. So let's say you are making a news reader, the `WebView's` base url will be the url of the original story.

Good Luck!

Also remember to set up your WebView...Like so...

```
    mContentWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mContentWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mContentWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
    mContentWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mContentWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

You need to have hardware acceleration turned on in the Manifest (only available on SDK 14 and above).

Ex. Hardware Acceleration On:

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.app"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<!-- hardwareAccelerated requires SDK 14 -->
...
</application>
```

Comment: avoiding loadDataWithBaseURL(...) with null base url worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Took me days to figure this out! I thought it would never work!!

Answer (score 3):

> **HTML5 Video support**
>
> In order to support inline HTML5 video in your application, you need to have **hardware acceleration turned on**, and **set a WebChromeClient**.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

(Hope it help someone)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me- the code opens youtube site and can play its videos inside WebView:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);     

WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


String frameVideo = "<html><body>Youtube video .. <br> <iframe width=\"320\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

mWebView.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");

mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/");

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some code to detect the environment of the user... use the iframe code only for ios devices (iphone, ipod, ipad) and use the old code for everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

> This Code made exactly fit to different device

```
webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    Log.e(SimpleBillsConstants.SIMPLE_BILLS, width + "-" + height);

    String data_html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html> <head> <meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"target-densitydpi=high-dpi\" /> <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"> <link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.5)\" href=\"hdpi.css\" /></head> <body style=\"background:black;margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;\"> <iframe style=\"background:black;\" width=' "+width+"' height='"+height+"' src=\""+ VIDEO_URL+"\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe> </body> </html> ";



    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://vimeo.com", data_html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```