# Youtube javascript api iframe playback on android - no Audio

Tags: android, google-chrome, iframe, youtube-javascript-api, android-mediacodec

This issue is only on youtube iframe playback on ( 4.3/4.4 on Nexus 7). I go to any media site embedding YT player in an Iframe and the sound does not play. The player will launch and will show controls but, no sound. The logcat msg is :

```
     I/OMXClient( 3004): Using client-side OMX mux.
    E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  180): Extension: OMX.google.android.index.storeMetaDataInBuffers not implemented
    E/OMXNodeInstance(  180): OMX_GetExtensionIndex OMX.google.android.index.storeMetaDataInBuffers failed
    E/ACodec  ( 3004): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648
...

I/OMXClient( 3004): Using client-side OMX mux.
E/OMXMaster( 3004): A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.
I/SoftAAC2( 3004): Reconfiguring decoder: 0->44100 Hz, 0->2 channels
D/audio_hw_primary(  180): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
D/ACDB-LOADER(  180): ACDB -> send_afe_cal
```

jsfiddle to [reproduce the bug](http://jsfiddle.net/rowntreerob/ynAtb/)  or just go to any media portal that embeds Youtube clips... this link is fine on my laptop and my phone. Its just the N7 where i've seen bug.

Workaround - use Chrome Beta as browser. But that does not really work if focus is on media heavy environment adapted for tablets.

My question: is it a Chrome problem or just a nexus 7 problem?

--EDIT
sample iframe from 'the dish' that has the issue:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/MYrY8aFCUCQ?version=3&amp;rel=1&amp;fs=1&amp;showsearch=0&amp;showinfo=1&amp;iv_load_policy=1&amp;wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" id="fitvid994988"></iframe>
```

Comment: do u have a youtube url that u want to play ??

Comment: http://dish.andrewsullivan.com/2013/11/14/why-humans-hate-poo/  the embed there does not play audio on the N7. That is good example

Comment: have u tried using webchromeclient

Comment: thanks will look at wcclient .. The main issue over creating web pages of instructions ( including youtube ) for a tablet app. If they use the tablet browser on the how-to pages to try to learn the app, the how-to videos don't play correctly. Does one need a separate , native how to app?

Comment: i gave you the answer as per the requirement for a native application development for playing it on webbrowser. Just check have you created a key for the youtube.

Comment: Would this answer help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592012/2371425