# Not able to view video in Android Web View

Tags: android, android-webview, android-mediaplayer

My web pages have emebedded video files using html5 video tags.

I have an embedded web server (NanoHTTPD) running which serves my file from file system.
Everything else works but when i click on play of the HTML5 video.
It gives the following error and the video is not played

```
  09-29 20:38:36.620: D/HTML5VideoInline(11532): HTML5VideoInline created
09-29 20:38:36.625: V/MediaPlayer(11532): setVideoSurfaceTexture
09-29 20:38:36.625: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(11532): reset
09-29 20:38:36.625: V/MediaPlayer(11532): reset
09-29 20:38:36.625: I/MediaPlayer(11532): path is null
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532): setDataSource IOException happend : 
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://10.207.114.115:8765/SLC/Book3_html/Book3/book/BO/demo.mp4
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:713)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:617)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:954)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at android.webkit.HTML5VideoView.prepareDataCommon(HTML5VideoView.java:326)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at android.webkit.HTML5VideoView.prepareDataAndDisplayMode(HTML5VideoView.java:363)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at android.webkit.HTML5VideoInline.prepareDataAndDisplayMode(HTML5VideoInline.java:72)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy$VideoPlayer.play(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:289)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy.handleMessage(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:465)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 20:38:36.640: D/MediaPlayer(11532): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

The media player goes to Content resolver which tries to load only files of content scheme. My uris are of http scheme.

My web view is plain simple one.

```
WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //webViewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    //webViewSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webViewSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    //webViewSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webViewSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
    //webViewSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    //WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
```

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16179544/6490462

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loadDataWithBaseURL.

See this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592012/850347

DON'T do this:

```
mContentWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, webViewContentString,
        "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

DO THIS INSTEAD:

```
//veryVeryVery important for playing the videos!
mContentWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(theBaseUrl, webViewConentString,
        "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an issue setting setDataSource(), make sure you are calling

```
setDataSource(String path)
```